# Extract string between two tags if it repeats more than once

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a xml log like below and I want to extract the value 1234656 if a string "Some Text"  repeats twice.

```
<Message  extract_id ="123456">
  <Tag1>
    <Type1>Some Text</Type1>
    <Type2>a</Type2>
    <Type3>b</Type3>
                .
                .
                .
                .
    <TypeN>Some Text</TypeN>
 </Tag1>
</Message>
```

Note : This xml is inside log file.

Can someone please help me with the grep or any other script ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use xml parsers for such cases

Comment: awk.. store the message then substring the value of typeN in to a hashmap with a counter.. if any of the values in the hashmap are greater than 1 then print out the message..

Comment: are you able t install `xmlstarlet`. Let me know